# How to use and what is the use lambda expression in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

Can anyone tell the use of lambda expression in Java 8?

I have tried the code below and could not get the meaning of the program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  state s = new state();
  MathOperation addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
  System.out.println(s.operate(10.1, 5.2, addition));
}

interface MathOperation {
  double operation(double a, double b);
}

private static double operate(double a, double b, MathOperation mo) {
  return mo.operation(a, b);
}
```

Comment: "can anyone tell the use of lambda expression in java8?".I flagged this questoin as too broad. You can read an entire book on this subject.

Comment: SO now has a neat Documentation section. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/91/lambda-expressions for an explanation of lambdas in Java 8.

Comment: kindly refer to the books or oracle documentation. Question is too broad!

Comment: I would look for a better example, you are not going to get the purpose from reading one example.

Answer (score 2):

Lambda expressions can be used where an instance of an interface that has only one method to implement is required. In this case,

```
MathOperation addition = ...
```

The `...` part expects a value compatible with `MathOperation`. But we are lazy, right? We don't want to create a class just for something simple like this:

```
class Addition implements MathOperation {
    public double operation(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}

// usage:
MathOperation addition = new Addition();
```

That's wayyyyy too long!

Then came anonymous classes, but they are kinda verbose as well:

```
MathOperation addition = new MathOperation() {
    public double operation(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

If you use lambda expressions, your code will be much cleaner:

```
MathOperation addition = (a, b) -> a + b;
```

The `(a, b)` part specifies the parameter's names. And the right-hand side of the `->` is the actual implementation of the interface method. If it is an expression, the `return` keyword is implicitly added. How nice!

"Wait a second! Where are the parameter's types?" you asked. Well, since everything can be inferred from the interface, there's no need to specify the types explicitly!

Now you have a variable called `addition` that stores an implementation of the interface `MathOperation`. The implementation is simply `return a + b`.

Now I think you can understand the rest of the code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

The program only calculates the sum of both Parameter. 
In your case 10.1 + 5.2

BTW: Read about the Java naming convention. Class names should be start with an uppercase letter

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this statement:

```
MathOperation addition = (a, b) -> a+b;
```

assigns `addition` to an object of a new anonymous class that `implements MathOperation`.  This class implements the `operation` method; the implementation adds its two arguments.  Something like

```
class SomeAnonymousClass implements MathOperation {
    @Override
    public double operation(double a, double b) {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

So when the `operation` method is used on object of this class (like `mo.operation` in your example), it will return the sum of the arguments.